# How can the Mouselistener be used ? to move buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, keylistener

I am currently working on a small boardgame. I have to place "objects" on a Button array. I thought of placing the objects are 1*1 1*2 etc,They are represented by disabled buttons. Is there any way that i can move the spawned Disabled Buttons with Keylisteners of my keyboard, since i cant get it to work

```
public GuiP1() {
    super();
    Panel.setLayout(null);
    this.add(Panel);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("BattleshipsP1");
    this.setSize(640, 1000);
    this.setVisible(false);
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

            if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                System.out.println("VK_RIGHT");
            } else if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                System.out.println("VK_LEFT");
            } else if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                System.out.println("VK_UP");
            } else if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                System.out.println("VK_DOWN");
            }
        }
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    Grid();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

It wont listen for keys beeing pressed

Thank you JFluX

Comment: Yes you can, but the devil's in the details, the details of your GUI and code, something you need to share with us. You would use a MouseAdapater and add it as both a MouseListener and a MouseMotionListener.

Comment: Please show any code as an edit to your original question, since as you can see, code does not format well in comments. Also comments are often not read, and so key components of your question should be inside your actual original question. Best if you could post a runnable [mcve] -- not your whole program, and not a link to code, but a small new program that shows us your problem -- check the link.

Comment: Also, please have a look at this [link to similar questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+mouselistener+move+buttons). You may get some decent ideas from them.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused now -- are we talking using a mouse or using a key listener?

Comment: I wasnt able to make a mouse listener work, so i started to try a keylistener which didntr work aswell so i have no idea what I can or could do ...

Comment: Alright stop. Please. Clarify your problem, stick with one problem, and maybe we can help. Shift all this stuff around, and you're going to leave us floundering. So in a few words please: *what are you trying to do, and where are you stuck?*

Comment: done. @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your KeyListeners are not working because the listened to component must be focusable and have focus for them to work. A kludge solution is to force the listened to component to have focus by

- making the listened to component focusable via `setFocusable(true)`
- By giving it the focus via `requestFocusInWindow()`
- and by making added components non-focusable by calling `setFocusable(false)` on them.

A much better solution is to use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which isn't tied as closely to component focus.